'Â' appearing in S3 output despite UTF8 encoding
I'm trying to get this notebook up and running. The goal of the Glue job is to pull multiple CSV files from s3, do some formatting and then push back to s3 as one file.  Upon running the glue job and pushing the output to s3, the file has 'Â' characters throughout.
Here is my setup:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import boto3
import io

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
S3_BUCKET_NAME = "bucket"
S3_PREFIX_Manufacturer = "Cost/Data_Source/Manufacturer"

def read_from_s3(object_key):
    file_content = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME, Key=object_key)["Body"].read()
    return pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(file_content),  header=0)


data = pd.DataFrame()
#Only using one file for simplicity, but function works with multiple files
manuf_data = ["Manufacturer_Report_(Jan5)_UTF8.csv"] 

for manuf in manuf_data: #concat all of the files together into one df
    object_key = f"{S3_PREFIX_Manufacturer}/{manuf}"
    df = read_from_s3(object_key)
    #print(manuf)
    data = pd.concat([data, df])

I believe the problem arises in my write_to_s3 function, because even without running the script - simply just reading the file from my s3 bucket into the Glue notebook and then sending right back, the Â characters appear anytime there is a space, indent, tab, etc.
Here is my write_to_s3 function:
def write_to_s3(df, bucket, key):
    body = df.to_csv(index=False, encoding="cp1252") #encoding="utf-8-sig"
    s3_client.put_object(Body=body, Bucket=bucket, Key=key)


processed_key = "Cost/Data_Source/Manufacturer/test.csv"
write_to_s3(data, S3_BUCKET_NAME, processed_key)

Example of the input file:



Part Number
Manufacturers
Manufacturer Code




112000
Zebra ~ Elephant
ZX123 ~ XY45


113000
Giraffe ~ Lion ~ Tiger
ABC-123 ~ 300100 ~ TIGER 23


114000
No Manufacturer Given
No Manufacturer Given



The exact same .csv file that gets put back into the s3 bucket via the function above:



Part Number
Manufacturers
Manufacturer Codes




112000
ZebraÂ ~ Elephant,Â Inc
ZX123Â ~ XY45


113000
GiraffeÂ Co. ~ LionÂ ~ TigerÂ Corp.
ABC-123 ~ 300100 ~ TIGERÂ 23


114000
No Manufacturer Given
No Manufacturer Given



To me, it seems like the encoding argument isn't working within the write_to_s3 function, and I have yet to find a fix that works, so any help on this would be much appreciated.

What it LOOKS like is that the text you have stored is in UTF-8, but you are displaying it as cp1252 or ISO-8859-1.  The character it's trying to display is the "non-breakable space", which has the value 0xA0 in cp1252, but gets written in UTF-8 as 0xC2 0xA0, and 0xC2 in cp1252 is displayed as "Â".

I would assume you're viewing the file with some Microsoft product.  They're famous for assuming your file is in the default Windows code page unless it has the UTF-8 BOM signature at the beginning of the file.  So the file is probably OK, you're just using an inappropriate viewer based on the observation by @TimRoberts.

@MarkRansom I have gotten rid of the encoding = 'cp1252' argument in the write_to_s3 function and even by just calling the file from my s3 bucket and putting it right back, the  "Â" still appear in the .csv output when I look at it in excel. So, is it really just an excel problem - and do you know of anyway I can change the viewing options to not have those display?

Remember what I said about Microsoft applications?  It goes double for Excel, because it doesn't give you a way to override its encoding assumption.  Put the UTF-8 signature on the file so Excel will know how to open it properly.

Sounds good, thank you very much
